# How to store in or print information from a binary *.dat file? C programming

Tags: c, data-structures, stream, fopen, binaryfiles

I want to store in or read information from a *.dat file that is in binary mode. The file has the following data (encoded in binary form):

```
License: 123456
Owner: John Doe
Value: 10000.00

License: IAMDOE
Owner: Jane Doe
Value: 20000.00
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXPLEN 80

typedef struct {    
    char none; /* used for registry initiated by '\0' ,should be ingnored */    
    char owner[MAXPLEN];
    char license[6];
    double value;
} veiculo_t;    


/* i need to use the following functions in the process */

void print_registry(veiculo_t *v)
{
    printf("Owner: %s - License: %.6s - Value: %.2lf \n", (*v).owner, (*v).license, (*v).value);
}

void read_registry(veiculo_t *v)
{
    char license2[8];
    printf("Name of the owner:\n");
    fgets((*v).owner,100,stdin);

    printf("License plate:\n");
    fgets(license2,10,stdin);
    memcpy(&(v->license),license2,6);

    printf("Value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&(*v).value);
}

int op_menu() 
{
    int op;
    printf("\n0 - end\n");
    printf("1 - insert\n");
    printf("2 - print\n");
    printf("option: ");
    scanf("%d",&op);  
    getchar();        
    return op;
}

int main()
{
    int op;
    op_menu();

    if (op=1){
        /* !!!!!HELP HERE!!!!!! */
    }

    if (op=2){
        FILE *f=fopen("veic.dat", "rb");
        if (f == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Not opened!\n");
        }
        else
            /* !!!!!HELP HERE!!!!!! */
    }
}
```

*dont know much about "streams"... A few hints would be apreciated!*

Comment: Are you sure the file is binary? I think it is text.

Comment: @BlackMamba it is binary, this is only one example of the kind information it contains (encoded in binary form)

Comment: hint: If the file is not opened and processed in text-mode, `scanf` is likely the *last* function you want to use. (and honestly not the function you want to use even if it *is* a text file). Likewise with `fgets()`, which expects a newline to stop parsing unless your field is the same length as your input buffer.

Comment: You can use `fread`, this is the link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: this may be helpful http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/9187/

Comment: @WhozCraig the scanf is only used to get the data from the user in the command line to then store in the file. In this programming exercise is mandatory to use those 2 functions: read_registry , print_registry .

Comment: @Bryant2 Thanks Bryant. I was wondering. BlackMamba is right. `fread` and `fwrite` are likely what you seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change the below otherwise you will never enter your "menu".

```
op = op_menu();    //op should be assigned by the return value of open_menu
if (op==1){...
if (op==2){...    // I believe you want '==' not '='
```

According the comments you have to invoke `read_registry` method. The added code:

```
    if (op==1){
        //insert
        veiculo_t *t = malloc(sizeof(veiculo_t));
        read_registry(t);
        FILE *f=fopen("veic.dat", "ab");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf("open file failed\n");
        }
        fwrite(t, sizeof(char), sizeof(*t), f);
        free (t);
    }

    if (op==2){
        //print
        FILE *f=fopen("veic.dat", "rb");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf("Not opened!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            veiculo_t *t = malloc(sizeof(veiculo_t));
            printf("sizeof t: %d\n", sizeof(*t));
            while(fread(t, sizeof(char), sizeof(*t), f))
                print_registry(t);
            free(t);
        }
```

The example code just for you refrence, I would like to provide a thinking more than an answer, but seems code always is clear and powerful. In below example I write file use append mode, if you want re-write file every time, change mode in `fopen` when write file.

Hope that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` and `fread` can be used for your needs.

Here's an example program that illustrates their usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   FILE* out = fopen("data.o", "wb");
   int i = atoi(argv[1]);
   fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, out);
   fclose(out);

   FILE* in = fopen("data.o", "rb");
   fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, in);
   fclose(in);

   printf("Number saved and restored from file: %d\n", i);
}
```

Results of executing the program:

```
>> ./test-51 2345
Number saved and restored from file: 2345
>> ./test-51 -200
Number saved and restored from file: -200
```

The size of the output file is, as you would expect, only 4 bytes.

```
>> wc data.o
0 1 4 data.o
```